# Upgrade/Update from mariadb 5.5 to 10

Tags: mysql, linux, centos, mariadb

Recently MariaDB 10 became stable.

MySQL 5.6 features were added to 10 release. I need to use some new features, so I'm interested:

Has anybody upgraded from MariaDB 5.5 to 10 on production server?
What is the upgrade path (simply changing mariadb repo to 10 will work?)?
Is the transition smooth?

Comment: Clearly off-topic and belongs to superuser or serverfault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have recently been through that exact upgrade, also on CentOS. We experienced no trouble at all with any of our databases, all using the InnoDB engine. I have enclosed our internal upgrade how-to, this may save you some time and show you which path we took.

This guide assumes you are running the AMD64 versjon og CentOS 6.

Create a yum repo file for MariaDB and name it /etc/yum.repos.d/MariaDB.repo

> ```
> [mariadb]
> name = MariaDB
> baseurl = http://yum.mariadb.org/10.0/centos6-amd64
> gpgkey=https://yum.mariadb.org/RPM-GPG-KEY-MariaDB
> gpgcheck=1
>
> // The signing key value is 0x1BB943DB.
> ```

Uninstall current MariaDB server and client. If yum was used to install them, use:

> ```
> yum remove mysql MySQL-server MySQL-shared MySQL-shared-compat
> ```

This should uninstall all packages depending on MariaDB/MySQL, and consequently requires you to reinstall php-mysql as described below. Any other packages depending on MySQL will also have to be reinstalled, so keep an eye out for this.

Install MariaDB

> yum install MariaDB-server MariaDB-client

Reinstall PHPs MySQL lib

> yum install php-mysql

Start MariaDB, update data files and restart Apache

```
service mysql start  
mysql_upgrade 
service httpd restart
```

Consider rebooting to test that all works as desired.

Comment: Thanks my upgrade process was flawless!

Comment: I also had to remove mariadb-libs on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade from version 5.5 to 10.0.12 was very smooth. 
All user databases and local accounts were automatically restored after the upgrade..

+-----------------+
| @@version       |
+-----------------+
| 10.0.12-MariaDB |

Note: You might need to restart the CentOS host if you notice a connection error:

Answer (score 0):

If you configured your root access to MySQL/MariaDB with a password, you need to use the -p option when you want to use mysql_upgrade.